# How to split tables among databases with JPA (Eclipselink)?

Tags: jpa

Is there a way to split a database using JPA (eclipselink)? I would like to separate the system data from the client data.

I would like to have relationship between them and if possible being one Persisence Unit.

Comment: What do you mean by split/separate?

Comment: As stated above "I would like to separate the system data from the client data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean.  But you can have two persistence units, one for a client database, and one for a system databases.

If you want to use them as a single persistence unit from your application, or want to have relationships between the two, you can use Composite Persistence Units in EclipseLink.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Composite_Persistence_Units